# Parameter of type (arrow function) | (arrow function) is typed as never instead of union of both

Tags: typescript

I want a type that can be `((x: string) => string) | ((x: number) => number)`

But when calling this function Typescript say that type of x cannot be assigned to string.

Here a simple example:

```js
const cellDataFormater: Record<string, ((x: string) => string) | ((x: number) => number)> = {
  string: (x: string) => x,
  float: (x: number) => x,
  int: (x: number) => x,
  date: (x: string) => x,
  boolean: (x: string) => x,
};

cellDataFormater['string']('toto'); // here typescript say that x of type cannot be assigned to string
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is const assertion an option for you? You can set your constant `as const` and you won't have any type issues:

```js
const cellDataFormater = {
  string: (x: string) => x,
  float: (x: number) => x,
  int: (x: number) => x,
  date: (x: string) => x,
  boolean: (x: string) => x,
} as const;

cellDataFormater['string']('toto'); // ok
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMCmAbRARAhlNAxEAnAthvLjALwwDeAsAFAwzS4CWYA5gFwwAUAHp4y1YBKMgD4YPADS16AM0QgMnXpzABXfACNiI0uKkyYLKMr4x1WnWInS6MACZFT-KMza79t+ppAhE8NDBnBldBDxtaAF8YNAg4cGgAblpaBGR0TBwCIlwAbQByATZ8gF0ufKgQSvyhRJgAenqYEABrWiA)